# Regex: match any word in a string that starts with "qwe"

Tags: regex

Say there are some strings

```
"abc qwe xyz"
"qwe abc xyz"
"abc xyz qwe"
"abc 123 zyx"
```

How to write an expression to locate the strings that contain words beginning with `"qwe"`?

(first 3 lines in our case)

Comment: Words in a string or whole strings?  Both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
\bqwe
```

The `\b` matches at a word boundary (the start or end of a word).

Answer (score 0):

in perl regex:

```
/\bqwe/
```

or, for ABC (case insensitive):

```
/\babc/i
```

where `\b` means 'word boundary'.